# Using Reads, Writes and Formats in Play framework

Tags: json, scala, validation, playframework, playframework-json

I have some models in a Play! application that I would like to serialize/deserialize to and from JSON. I used to have separate methods for that, but I have seen that the preferred way is to give an implicit instance of `Formats[T]` or `Reads[T]`, like

```
import play.api.libs.json.{ JsValue, Reads } 

case class Foo(bar: Int, ...)

object Foo {
  implicit object FooReads extends Reads[Foo] {
    def reads(json: JsValue): Foo = //whatever
  }
}
```

Now, it may happen that the model has the correct fields in the JSON, but it does not validate. In this case, I am not able to deserialize - I should get an exception when using `json.as[Foo]` or `None` when using `json.asOpt[Foo]`.

If I throw an exception when I find a field that does not validate, everything seems to work as expected. But I took the care of trying to find out what exception I should throw, and in the source for `JsValue` I found this

```
def asOpt[T](implicit fjs: Reads[T]): Option[T] = fjs.reads(this).fold(
    valid = v => Some(v),
    invalid = _ => None
  ).filter {
  case JsUndefined(_) => false
  case _ => true
}
```

Now, I cannot understand how this is supposed to work. The implicit instance of `fjs` is supplied by myself in the companion object, so I know that `fjs.reads(this)` either returns a `Foo` or throws an exception.

Where is this `fold` coming from? It certainly is not a method on `Foo`. I guess one could have an implicit conversion, but it should be from `Any` to something with a `fold` method, so it could not be of much interest. Even worse, if `fjs.reads(this)` throws an exception, there is nothing to catch it!

> So, how should one handle invalid input in the JSON in an instance of `Reads[T]`? And how does the mechanism above actually work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [JsonValue.scala](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.0.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsValue.scala) in Play 2.0.x:

```
def asOpt[T](implicit fjs: Reads[T]): Option[T] = catching(classOf[RuntimeException]).opt(fjs.reads(this)).filter {
  case JsUndefined(_) => false
  case _ => true
}
```

In fact the code is using [scala.util.control.Exception.catching[T](exceptions: Class[_]*): Catch[T]](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.util.control.Exception%24), which returns a `Catch[T]`. Then it calls opt(...) on it. If an exception is thrown, then it will return a None instead of an instance of `T`.

So, when you get an error deserializing, you can safely throw an exception.

Comment: That absolutely makes sense. Now I am left wondering which version I was browsing yesterday when I found the other definition without the `catching`. :-? Too bad I did not include the link...

Comment: Ok, I found it https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsValue.scala It is the version in master, which probably is the codebase for Play 2.1. I should have looked better...